# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SessionsController#create /SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, activerecord, sqlite

I am trying to create a facebook login my ap and i get this error at runtime when sigin in with facebook is clicked

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SessionsController#create
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.provider: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "users"."uid" = 'FACEBOOK KEY' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

    Extracted source (around line #6):
    4      def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    5      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    6      user.provider = auth.provider
    7      user.uid = auth.uid
    8      user.name = auth.info.name

Rails.root:/selfstarter

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:6:in `from_omniauth'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

Here is the code from user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end


end
```

Here is the code from sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a `provider` column in the `users` table?

Comment: Did you miss a migration that would have added the `provider` column to your `users` table?

Comment: There is a provider column in the users table and i have run the  migration  too but i am still getting the same error